# R programming- find lowest value

Tags: r

I've just started learning R. I wanted to know how can I find the lowest value in a column for a unique value in other column. For example, in this case I wanted to know the lowest avg price per year. 
I have a data frame with about 7 columns, 2 of them being average price and year. The year is obviously recurrent ranges from 2000 to 2009. The data also has various NA's in different columns. 
I have very less idea about running a loop or whatsoever in this regard. 
Thank you :)
my data set looks something like this:
avgprice  year
332       2002
NA        2009
5353      2004 
1234      NA   and so on.
To break down my problem to find first five lowest values from year 2000-2004.

```
s<-subset(tx.house.sales,na.rm=TRUE,select=c(avgprice,year)
s2<-subset(s,year==2000)
s3<-arrange(s2)
tail(s2,5)
```

I know the code fails miserably. I wanted to first subset my dataframe on the basis of year and avgprice. Then sort it for each year through 2000-2004. Arrange it and using tail() print the lowest five. However I also wanted to ignore the NAs

Comment: Try `aggregate(averageprice~year, df1, FUN=min)`

Comment: First step in finding a solution is making a reproducible example. Second is trying to find the terminology associated with what you're after. In your case, you should be looking for ways to "find min per year". After everything has failed, show us the example and the code you tried but didn't work. A must have is also what the expected result would look like.

Comment: @Roman Lustrik I wanted to ask for the same df, I want to find the five lowest values of avg price between years 2002 and 2008. I tried with the following code but I think I'm messing up something. 
df1<-subset(tx.house.sales,na.rm=TRUE,select=c(avgprice,year)) 
df2<-subset(df1,year==2000) 
df3-arrange(df2) 
tail(df3,5)

The follwing code gives errors. I'm not sure if Im using the subset function correctly. Thank you. Also I wanted a bit clarity on how na.rm and omit() work, do they ignore the complete row with NA or just not consider that cell. Im using a .csv file.

Comment: @akrun Also if I wanted to consider a combination of say two columns, say to find lowest price for combination of each year and city. How can I do that?

Comment: @saheebabatra In that case, change the `group_by` statement in the `dplyr` code to `group_by(year, city)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
aggregate(averageprice~year, df1, FUN=min)
```

#### Update

If you need to get 5 lowest "averageprice" per "year"

```
 library(dplyr)
 df1 %>% 
     group_by(year) %>% 
     arrange(averageprice) %>%
     slice(1:5)
```

Or you could use `rank` in place of `arrange`

```
df1 %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    filter(rank(averageprice, ties.method='min') %in% 1:5)
```

This could be also done with `aggregate`, but the 2nd column will be a list

```
 aggregate(averageprice~year, df1, FUN=function(x)
                 head(sort(x),5), na.action=na.pass)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(year=sample(2002:2008, 50, replace=TRUE), 
       averageprice=sample(c(NA, 80:160), 50, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: I wanted to ask for the same df, I want to find the five lowest values of avg price between years 2002 and 2008. I tried with the following code but I think I'm messing up something.

    s<-subset(tx.house.sales,na.rm=TRUE,select=c(avgprice,year))
    s2<-subset(s,year==2000)
    s3<-arrange(s2)
    tail(s2,5)

The follwing code gives errors. I'm not sure if Im using the subset function correctly. Thank you.
Also I wanted a bit clarity on how na.rm and omit() work, do they ignore the complete row with NA or just not consider that cell. Im using a .csv file.

Comment: @saheebabatra Could you update in your post with an example dataset and the expected result based on that.  From the comments, it is difficult to understand what you want.  From looking at the `subset` code, I think there are some typos, mistakes in the code.

Comment: To break down the above problem
my data set looks something like this:
    avgprice               year

Comment: @saheebabatra Updated the post, please check

Comment: thank you so much. I wanted to know if I could do it using subset? Because,Im sure even though your code works. I wanted to know how to work with subsets. Please see I have update the post, you can see how i wanted to go about the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @saheebabatra Yes, you could do it with `subset` after splitting by `year`

Comment: @saheebabatra A base R option with `split` would be `do.call(rbind,lapply(split(df1, df1$year), function(x) head(x[order(x$averageprice),],5)))`